# Maximum value of $\frac{a}{1+bc} + \frac b{1+ac} + \frac{c}{1+ab}$ given $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Given that the constraint of $a, b, c$, for which $a, b, c$ are non-negative real numbers, is $a^2+b^2+c^2=1,$ find the maximum value of $$\frac{a}{(1+bc)}+\frac b{(1+ac)}+\frac{c}{(1+ab)}.$$

For this question I have tried using this geometric method, hopefully it can be logically correct

Do you all have actually better method(s) to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Due to the symmetry of the problem, is seems quite likely that $a=b=c = \sqrt \frac 13$ will be a critical point.

Comment: @Doug M Are you sure? For non-negative variables we can get something greater.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It’s a critical point, but not necessarily a local maximum.

Comment: @amd We need to find a maximal value and not a critical point. The critical point, which does not give a maximal value is not necessary.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don’t disagree, but my point was that Doug M only pointed out that something interesting happens when the values of the variables are equal, so it’s a simple case that’s worth investigating, **not** that a maximum must occur there.

Answer (score 1):

For non-negative variables we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+bc}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a\sqrt2}{a+b+c}=\sqrt2$$
because $$2(1+bc)^2\geq(a+b+c)^2$$ it's
$$2+4bc+2b^2c^2\geq1+2(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$2b^2c^2+(b+c-a)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs fot $c=0$ and $a=b=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$ which says that we got a maximal value.